# Table width not apply

Tags: html, css

i am using some table for showing data from database but i am try every thing to change table width but i did't.I have been using inline width,important,also id,and class but all of fail.Yes one think i want to clear there when i apply width on simple i mean with out dynamic data.than work fine.i am showing picture below.

```
<table border="1" style="width: 18px !important;" >
 <?php
        include("db.php");
        $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books");

$f0 = mysql_field_name( $result1,0);
$f1 = mysql_field_name( $result1,1);
$f2 = mysql_field_name( $result1,2);
$f3 = mysql_field_name( $result1,3);
$f4 = mysql_field_name( $result1,4);
$f5 = mysql_field_name( $result1,5);
$f6 = mysql_field_name( $result1,6);
$f7 = mysql_field_name( $result1,7);
$f8 = mysql_field_name( $result1,8);
$f9 = mysql_field_name( $result1,9);
$f10 = mysql_field_name( $result1,10);
 echo "<th>".$f0."</th>";
echo "<th>".$f1."</th>";
echo "<th>".$f2."</th>";
echo "<th>".$f3."</th>";
echo "<th>".$f4."</th>";
echo "<th>".$f5."</th>";
echo "<th>".$f6."</th>";
echo "<th>".$f7."</th>";
 echo "<th>".$f8."</th>";
  echo "<th>".$f9."</th>";
   echo "<th>".$f10."</th>";



        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books");


        while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $test['BookID'];

            echo "<tr>";    
            echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['BookID']."</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['name']."</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['father_name']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['monthly_income']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['wasiyat_number']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['wasiyat_fund']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['tahrikaa_jadid_fund']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['waqfi_jadid_fund']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['local_fund']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['jalsa_salana_fund']. "</font></td>"; 
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['total']. "</font></td>";
            include("permissions.php");         
            echo"<td> <a href ='datamanage/view.php?BookID=$id'>Edit</a>";
            echo"<td> <a href ='datamanage/del.php?BookID=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";

            echo "</tr>";}


        mysql_close($conn);


        ?>
        </table>
```

[image: Width not applying]

Comment: The width is too small for the table contents and headers.

Comment: Post your rendered HTML and CSS here; the PHP is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter how small you tell it to be, the table will make itself a minimum width to contain all the necessary data or column headings or whatever.  (depending on the browser) it's not an image that can be shrunk down infinitely; those characters take up a certain amount of pixels on the page and that's the smallest your table will be.  You can shrink the font down to the minimum, but you're trying to have an 18px wide table with 10 columns, and I don't think it will happen.

Here's another q&a dealing with the same issue [Rendered pIxel width data for each character in a browser's font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162730/rendered-pixel-width-data-for-each-character-in-a-browsers-font)